# Почему компилятор react выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему появляется ошибка компиляции? Если переменные "nextDays" и "activeDay" передаются корректно

App.js

```
import AvailableDates from "./components/AvailableDates";

function App() {

  const [nextDays, setNextDays] = useState(['loading...']);
  const [activeDay, setActiveDay] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    async function datesInit() {
      const days = await getNextDays(today)
      setNextDays(days)
      setActiveDay(days[0])
    }
    datesInit()
  },[])


  return (
    <div>
      <AvailableDates nextDays={nextDays} activeDay={activeDay} setActiveDay={setActiveDay}/>
    </div>
  );

}
```

AvailableDates.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const AvailableDates = ({nextDays, activeDay, setActiveDay}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Ближайшие даты:
            {nextDays.map(day =>
                <button
                    key={day}
                    onClick={()=>setActiveDay(day)}
                >
                    {day}
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AvailableDates;
```

Error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src\components\AvailibleDates.jsx
  Line 7:14:   'nextDays' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 11:36:  'activeDay' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: не props не передались, а какой-то агрессивный линтер не дает скомпилировать код

Comment: @dmitry-kozlov, Что это значит? Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ошибка просто перестала появляться, я не знаю, почему, ничего не менял...